# How to separate PHP code and Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I separate javascript from PHP when the JS needs a PHP variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316203/how-can-i-separate-javascript-from-php-when-the-js-needs-a-php-variable)
>   [How to define a variable in JavaScript with PHP echo function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734338/how-to-define-a-variable-in-javascript-with-php-echo-function)

For example I have the following Javascript code. It uses PHP variables.

```
<script>
 $(function() {
     for(var items = 1; items <=<?php echo $items;?>; items++){
         print_percentage_is("div.is"+items);
     }
});
</script>
```

What's the best solution to separate the Javascript code with my Html/PHP code? For this case I can not use this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/change.js"></script>
```

Do I need to create a PHP file and put the javascript in? What's the best solution?

Comment: Best solution would probably be AJAX. Mixing PHP and JS like that is never a good idea.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? Use Ajax to load javascript?

Comment: Using AJAX to load required variables.

Comment: Need more detail on exactly what you want to achieve. If it is just to strip the php out, you could server the page, open it in a browser and grab the source which would be the raw HTML/JS.

Comment: @Sop: The overall concept is to use AJAX to get the variable from PHP and store it in a JS variable. Then you do whatever you need to do with it and when you're done you send that variable back to the server. You'd typically use JSON to share data between client and server. This way you keep everything neat and separate, but connected.

Comment: You can use a global JavaScript variable that you can dump into your html and still can use your script the way you just mentioned.
`<script>
GlobalData  = { <? json_encode($items) ; ?> };
</script>`
and then in you javascript you will be using GlobalData object.

Comment: @elclanrs AJAX doesn't work well if the variable needs to be used directly in the page.

Answer (score 1):

If data needs to be directly available to your JavaScript, AJAX is a pretty horrendous solution. Instead, you can create a separate `<script>` tag to pass the PHP variables over to the page, using `json_encode()`.

This is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_variable = <?php echo json_encode($my_variable); ?>;
</script>
```

In the page you would then use it like so:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    console.log(my_variable);
});
</script>
```

If you need to pass multiple variables, it's sometimes better to group them together in PHP like this:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'items' => array(1,2,3,4),
    'users' => array(array('name' => 'John'), array('name' => 'Jane')),
);
?>
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    console.log(data.items);
    console.log(data.users);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see how AJAX is a bad solution... It works just fine http://jsbin.com/ohosuf/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs I'm not saying it's bad, but if your server side application already has the data when the page is rendered I don't see why AJAX should even be used but for the fewest of occasions.

Answer (score 0):

set a header for javascript (`application/javascript`) in a php file. then in the `script` tag, point the `src` attribute to that file. Do whatever echoing (or conditionals, retrieving) is needed in that respective php file.